# HTTP 403 - Image does not show in IE but shows in all other browsers

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, .net-2.0, windows-server-2008

I have a asp.net 2.0 app.
It is using its own application domain.
My application has an image on the following page:

http://www.executivepoolandspa.com/default.aspx

There is an image on the following page on the bottom right which DOES NOT show in IE. But it shows in other browsers..

Here is the image: http://www.executivepoolandspa.com/dynamicdata/images/img258_CPOLogo.jpg

I am stuck. I changed the application pool in IIS7 windows server 2008 web edition to use network service identity but it is still not working.

I use my own CMS to upload this image. The image is saved to a folder.(dynamicdata/images).

Any suggestions.

Comment: Also, you are not getting an HTTP 403 on that image.  The image is being returned fine, no matter the browser.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your image is in CYMK color space.  Some browsers can load CMYK images, but many cannot, IE included.  Convert it to RGB, and you're good to go.  You can use Photoshop or [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) for this.

Here is a converted version for you, resized to the size you need it:

[image: CPO Certified]

You shouldn't use 700k images on your site.  That's a ton of bandwidth.  This version is 14k.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file is corrupt.  I had similar issue before.

Try downloading the file, opening it with your favorite picture editor (photoshop/paint/ifranview), then upping it back to the server. It did the trick for me.